# Find all path combinations

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

Don't know if this has a specific name, but I need to flatten an array of 1D arrays and simple elements, in a way that all combinations untill a leaf "node" are reported. Here's an example because the above leaves a lot to the imagination:

```js
// My input array contains single elements or 1D arrays:
let input = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]];
```

The unfolding proceeds so that each time an array is encountered, the paths are split into as many elements as the array contains:

```js
// current result = [1, 2]
// unconsumed input [[3, 4], [5, 6]]
// ->
// current result = [ [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4] ]

// current result = [ [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4] ]
// unconsumed input [[5, 6]]
// ->
// final result = [ [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4, 6] ]
```

I may be messing something up with copies and aliasing but can't seem to make it work right and handle special cases like:

```js
let input1 = [1, 2, 3]; // No nested arrays
let input2 = [];        // Empty input
```

Tried building the result backwards since `.pop` is convenient to use here but can't get it to work:

```js
function flatPath(input, result = [[]]) {
    while (input.length) {
        const last = input.pop();

        if (Array.isArray(last)) {
            result = flatPath(last, [...result, ...result]);
        } else {
            for (let ar of result) {
                result.push(last);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let result = flatPath([1, 2, [3, 4], [2, 5, 6] ]);

console.log(result);
```

but can't even get past compilation (I'm using typescript) since all I get is:

> Parameter 'input' implicitly has an 'any' type.

> Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

What is the problem with my code or is there a better (more idiomatic) way to do this.

Comment: you may try https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMANgQygBQwCwBQxgAOIUAXInmCALYBGApgE6IA+i19zA2gLoCUffhU6MmfPogDeAKESIUDKIiYjaYib0QBeRNz68A3HORwWeRcrQATaw2uI4wRIRJR+0k-MuIbd6wCCTCy6QUxoAJ4AdDAAzmGReH72HgD8vrb2iBTcydZGXio6KlGoGACyaER4REwMAG46AHwZ-mFRNFVJzXpRfbUNADS+AvwmAL4mdVAgTEhMxpOgkLAIyOhYuACMBMSkFFTqzGwcR+ICQmpc55Ky8tOzSK6kJh1dDD0J0XFfeAxpiA+OQYAledWsIAgDAAPKIeLw+E08DU6vVhnkPNoWnd5ColI9WvZShtKtU0D0BvU3tUiD1uH0okR0aMJsN9LxQZMZD46rEQChlLoypsoPhuFthgAmNkAZmGABZeGzpYgAKzDABsHP4xhkEAQsTgiiiKDgAHM8Lz+e5DEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this without passing down a context array by aggregating the results from the bottom up here using `map()` to add each non-array element from the previous call to the returned sub-arrays from deeper calls.

```js
function flatPath([next, ...rest]) {
  if (next === undefined) {
    return [[]];
  }

  if (Array.isArray(next)) {
    const temp = [];
    for (const n of next) {
      temp.push(...flatPath([n, ...rest]));
    }
    return temp;
  }

  return flatPath(rest).map(t => [next, ...[].concat(t)]);
}


// Test output
for (const test of [
  [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]],
  [1, 2, 3], 
  [[1, 2, 3], 4], 
  []
]) {
  let result = flatPath(test);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}

 // [[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,4,6]]
 // [[1,2,3]]
 // [[1,4],[2,4],[3,4]]
 // [[]]
```

The above will fail if you have an `undefined` element in your array which is fixed below by checking against the `...rest` length to determine the bottom (and an explicit check for empty arrays passed as input).

```js
function flatPath(input) {
  if (input.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  const [next, ...rest] = input;

  if (Array.isArray(next)) {
    const temp = [];
    for (const n of next) {
      const tail = rest.length
        ? flatPath([n, ...rest])
        : flatPath([].concat(n));

      temp.push(...tail);
    }
    return temp;
  }

  return rest.length
    ? flatPath(rest).map(t => [next, ...[].concat(t)])
    : [next];
}

// Test output
for (const test of [
  [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]],
  [1, 2, 3], 
  [[1, 2, 3], 4], 
  []
]) {
  let result = flatPath(test);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}

 // [[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,4,6]]
 // [[1,2,3]]
 // [[1,4],[2,4],[3,4]]
 // [[]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use-case for a generator function, because it allows you to `yield` results at the leave notes (whose cardinality is unknown a-priori), rather having to handle the aggregation back up the calling tree of the recursion.

```js
const flatPath = function*(array, prefix = []) {
  const next = array[0];
  if (next === undefined) { // base case
    yield prefix;
  } else if (next instanceof Array) {
    for (let item of next) {
      yield * flatPath(array.slice(1), [...prefix, item]);
    }
  } else {
    yield * flatPath(array.slice(1), [...prefix, next]);
  }
};

const result = Array.from(flatPath([1, 2, [3, 4], [2, 5, 6]]));
console.log(result);

/* output:
[
  [ 1, 2, 3, 2 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 5 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 6 ],
  [ 1, 2, 4, 2 ],
  [ 1, 2, 4, 5 ],
  [ 1, 2, 4, 6 ]
]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to compile your code but it goes into infinite loop. I think the problem is this part;

```
        for (let ar of result) {
            result.push(last);
        }
```

You are pushing elements to the `result` array while iterating over it. This causes an infinite loop.

To fix this issue, you can create a separate array to store the new elements and then concatenate it with the `result` array outside the loop.

The following works fine;

```
        const newElements = [];
        for (let ar of result) {
            newElements.push(last);
        }
        result = result.concat(newElements);
```

Answer (score 1):

This version, written independently, expresses the same algorithm as the answer from pilchard.  But it cleans some things up and uses pure expressions rather than statements, as I always prefer:

```js
const process = ([xs, ...xss], rs = xs !== undefined && process(xss)) =>
  xs === undefined
    ? [[]]
  : Array.isArray(xs)
    ? xs.flatMap(x => rs.map(r => [x, ...r]))
  : rs.map(r => [xs, ...r]);

const input = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]]

console .log(JSON.stringify(process (input)))
```

Pilchard's answer also expressed concern over possibly `undefined` values in the input.  If that is a concern, an easy solution would be to introduce a `Symbol`, like this:

```js
const None = Symbol()

const process = ([xs = None, ...xss], rs = xs !== None && process(xss)) =>
  xs === None
    ? [[]]
  : Array.isArray(xs)
    ? xs.flatMap(x => rs.map(r => [x, ...r]))
  : rs.map(r => [xs, ...r])

const input = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

But I wouldn't bother unless you expect -- and want to handle -- `undefined` values.